# Heroku Deploy Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku, graphql

I tried to deploy app node js on Heroku, but Heroku does not detect the package.json in the app folder.

pls help me, I have to finish my project. Thanks

- Edit : index file in app folder and package.json also

Below is my structure code:

[image]

Comment: Are you using the Heroku CLI or directly from the dashboard?
Check de docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs?singlepage=true#prepare-the-app

Comment: I am using git push Heroku master to put code into Heroku. But Heroku said he doesn't detect the structure of Nodejs app. I already tried to change the behaivior of the buildpack but that was still not  success

Comment: verify 1. package.json in project root 2. .gitignore does NOT bypass package.json in a push 3. redo git push with force to just replay the push action that failed earlier

Comment: my package.json is not in the root, that is in-app folder :)) maybe I have to find other free cloud alternatives for Heroku

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this might be late but I think your package.json file should be outside the src folder and in the main app folder. Heroku will detect the package.json file in the root directory (here is the app directory). It will then run the script cd app from the main (app) directory and do npm build and npm start.

I faced a similar issue where I thought the package.json file of the backend to run server.js in my backend folder would be enough to host in Heroku. But I realised later that only the main root package.json (which would be in your app directory here) is considered.

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiHmF.png)

I fixed it by having the start script in the package.json in my main directory. (which would be you app directory here). I was able to deploy on Heroku after this sucessfully.

```
"scripts": {
"start": "cd server && node server.js"
}
```